# Convert Lead to Opportunity via data loader

Tags: data-loader, lead-conversion

I'd like to convert leads to existing/new accounts with opportunities using data loader. How do I go about it? Also, which all fields do I need to map in data loader?

Comment: Please try to find and use tags related to the question. This should help you attract people with the right knowledge to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert a lead to an account/contact/opportunity using the data loader. The reason why is because the Data Loader only supports the following operations: query, queryAll, queryMore, insert, upsert, update, and delete (note: you can't even undelete records in the Data Loader).

What you need is a tool capable of calling convertLead. There are several free and paid tools on the [AppExchange](http://www.appexchange.com/) that can do this given various types of input data (such as a campaign, etc).